# To show a set $(X\times Y)-(A\times B)$ is connected .

Tags: general-topology

Let  $A$  be a proper subset of of $X$, $B$ be a proper subset of $Y$. If $X$ and $Y$ are connected, show that $(X\times Y)-(A\times B)$ is connected.

Comment: $\mathbb R^2-\mathbb Q^2$ is connected!

Answer (score 3):

Let $a\in X-A$, $b\in Y-B$.
Assume $U,V$ are disjoint nonempty open subsets covering $(X\times Y)\setminus (A\times B)$. And wlog. $(a,b)\in U$.
Since $V$ is nonempty, let $(x,y)\in V$. Then $x\in X-A$ or $y\in Y-B$. Wlog. the former.
Then $\{x\}\times Y$ is connected (homeomorphic to $Y$) and covered by the disjoint open sets $U,V$.
From $(x,y)\in V$, we conclude $\{x\}\times Y\subseteq V$.
Likewise, we conclude that $X\times \{b\}\subseteq U$.
But then $(x,b)\in U\cap V$, contradiction.

Comment: I really don't understand how U ,V is a cover of {x}XY? Where U and V are open cover of (XXY)\(AXB).