# $(X\times Y)-(A\times B)$ is connected

Tags: general-topology

> Let $A$ be a proper subset of $X$ and let $B$ be a proper subset of $Y$. If $X$ and $Y$ are connected, show that $$(X\times Y)-(A\times B)$$ is connected.

$$(X\times Y)-(A\times B)=[X\times (Y-B)]\cup [(X-A)\times Y-X\times (Y-B)]$$

Case 1: If $X\times (Y-B)$ connected, $(X\times Y)-(A\times B)$ is also connected.

Case 2: If $(X-A)\times Y-X\times (Y-B)$ connected, $(X\times Y)-(A\times B)$ is also connected.

Case 3: The first set $X\times (Y-B)$ is separated in two sets and the other set $(X-A)\times Y-X\times (Y-B)$ is separated in two sets. Note that since $X$ is connected, $\overline{[X\times (Y-B)]}\cap [(X-A)\times Y-X\times (Y-B)]$ is not null set or $[X\times (Y-B)]\cap \overline{[(X-A)\times Y-X\times (Y-B)]}$ is not null set. Hence $(X\times Y)-(A\times B)$ is connected.

---

**But I think** it would be better if I can write down **the separations** of $X\times (Y-B)$ and $(X-A)\times Y-X\times (Y-B)$, otherwise I feel like my argument will remain **vague**. I could not find those specific sets [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44807/if-x-and-y-are-connected-then-x-times-y-setminusa-times-b-is-connecte) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423765/to-show-a-set-x-times-y-a-times-b-is-connected) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214317/prove-that-x-times-y-setminus-a-times-b-is-connected) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934259/show-that-x-times-y-setminus-a-times-b-is-connected).

Can anyone tell me what are the what are the four partitions actually??

**Note:** I don't need a solution of the problem. Links I gave have already plenty of solutions.

Comment: This doesn't really sound meaningful -- you keep speaking about "separated in two sets" without ever talking about whether anything is open and/or closed.

Comment: Xx(Y - B) may not be seperated.  For example, X = Y = R, B = (0,oo).

Comment: @WilliamElliot yes... but but those cases trivially says that $(X\times Y)-(A\times B)$ connected. I think, I need to add a little in my argument...

Comment: @HenningMakholm I can not specify open or closed since, it is not given that $A, B$ are open or closed, isn't?

Comment: @HenningMakholm it would be good if you clarify me, as you see I started topology recently, so I don't want to make holes in my concept in this topic...

Comment: @WilliamElliot also I edited... inspired by your comment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw a picture. Pick $p \in X -A$, $q \in Y-B$, and use that for $x \notin A$, the set $Y_x = \{x\} \times Y$ lies in $X\times Y - A \times B$ and is connected as a homeomorph of $Y$. The same holds for $X_y = X \times \{y\}$ for $y \notin B$, using $X$ is connected.

Suppose $(x,y), (x',y') \in X \times Y  -A \times B$. Connect them using unions of sets of the form $X_l (l \notin B)$ and $Y_m (m \notin A)$ that intersect each other one to the next (so sets like $S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3$ with $S_1 \cap S_2 \neq \emptyset$ and $S_2 \cap S_3 \neq \emptyset$. (There are some cases depending on e.g. whether $x \notin A$ or $y \notin B$) This implies these unions are connected and completely inside $X \times Y - A \times B$, and so the latter set is connected as well.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I wanted what are those $4$ partitions (Also I found an error, which was pointed out by William Elliot. Apart from those type of problems, can you tell me)

Comment: I just edited a little.... can you tell for only case 3?

Comment: There are 4 cases for $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$,: $x \notin A$ or $y \notin B$ and independently $x' \notin A$ or $y' \notin B$. These are the 4 combined cases to consider,